# Windows vs OS X temperature, Windows runs hotter

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, temperature

I could see about 10 degrees celsius less when idle in OS X, compared to Windows 8.1, that's ~49 °C compared to ~38 °C.
I've seen that, according to Macs fan control, the fan is shut down in idle, but after googling, some people say macbook should always keep fan running at around 1200 rpm.

Should I leave it as is or would it be safer to use a custom fan management to keep it running at 1200 rpm?

Specs: MacBook Pro Retina 13" 2015

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend changing you fan-speed management if you are not sure about it. 38°C - 49°C won't harm your macbook.

Comment: That's 49 degrees Celsius after  booting, but opening a browser and actually using it for light tasks will have it run at around 55-60 degrees.

Comment: I won't fear those temperatures :) even 95°C shouldn't harm your CPU (I'm glad we aren't in the 90's anymore) ... Try out playing a game and measure the CPU temperature - it will be much higher than 60°C.

Comment: Agreed, but still don't know why Apple would choose to stop the fan when idle. Probably they didn't think someone would use Windows exclusively.

Comment: ... or maybe they don't want to ?